# How to add ad-mob (Advertisement banner) Top OR Bottom of the Imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, admob, android-linearlayout

I have 3 Linear Layouts, first layout for Image View, second layout for two buttons i.e. next, previous and third i added for `admob` but problem is that my `admob(Advertisement)` take extra space for advertisement but I want to shown top OR bottom position of the image, how I can set it's XML?

I want my ad banner look like this on image, not taking extra space:
[image]

My XML:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? >

< LinearLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:maxHeight="91dip"
        android:maxWidth="47dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/p1"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="aasdf74546adsf"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
             >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" 
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bGeri"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#d6d6d6"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIleri"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#d6d6d6"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @AM : i don't want to image clickable change, i just want to show add banner top or bottom of the image.

Comment: and also as per your comment when i changed my Root layout (LinearLayout) to FrameLayout then my image will not showing??

Comment: What do want do adnan? Want to show An admob below or above the image view or you want to show admob overlaying your image view ie on top of the image view.

Comment: @A.R. i trying too much too upload imageView snapshot to clarify my problem but every time its showing "you need to atleast 10 reputation to post images", i don't why, By the way i tell you that in my case i have 90% image on my screen and in 10% area i have two button for "Next image" and "Previous Image" and i want to show ads bottom of the imageview and above the both buttons without decreasing my image width and height size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, it may help you.

Create xml file eg.

main.xml

```
<merge 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/p1" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a152fe7ceceb49a"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now include this main.xml file in you activity_main.xml like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/main" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/bGeri"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#d6d6d6"
    android:text="Previous"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</Button>

     <Button
    android:id="@+id/bIleri"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#d6d6d6"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this resolves your problem

Comment: Thanks Alot @A.R. By applying your code i get that's i want... 
You save my time...
your help is really appreciated.. Stay Blessed!

Comment: Your most welcome adnan, If answer is useful to you. Please accept my answer. As someone else facing the same problem as you are facing, and my answer is accepted by you they can get a help out of it too. Accepted answer is always useful to others too. Ok

Comment: Accepting the answer means you need to tick the right mark dear.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative layout, and align parent bottom :

```
 <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#000000"
 >


    <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="aasdf74546adsf"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
     >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: By Applying you code i.e. relative layout and align parent bottom="true".... now my image not showing ??

Comment: Yes but you need to put something else in layout_height since it's not a Linear layout anymore, not 0dp

Comment: i have changed to it to wrap_content, now image showing but my ads banner hidden backside of the  both buttons